# Wrong value when ion-radio changed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm getting a strange error when trying to change the radio button value and posting it in my soap writeData. For example I'm trying to change the gender from M to F, I console.log it and the value in result of the change is like this: rb-1-0

This is my code:

```
<div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:23%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">
    <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="F" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'f'"></ion-radio>
    <span>
      <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%; margin-left: 2%;font-size:16px">F</strong>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div radio-group formControlName="gender" style="margin-left: 47%;margin-top: -10%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO"
  class="radio-privacy in-middle">
    <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="M" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'm'"></ion-radio>
    <span>
      <strong style="position: absolute;margin-top: -1%;margin-left: 4%;font-size:16px">M</strong>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work fine for a normal radio button group, please customize the CSS as required.

```
<ion-list radio-group style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:23%" [(ngModel)]="customer.SESSO">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
    <ion-radio color="dark" value="F" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'F'"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
    <ion-radio color="dark" value="M" [checked]="customer.SESSO == 'M'"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend you to use the .scss file for CSS and not use inline CSS as its more cleaner and readable that way. Cheers.

Comment: no way I finally found what the error was... [value]="" is wrong the correct one is value="", your answer helped me realise it. Thanks fixed just doing this simple change